# Change labels in slicknav when open/closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu, slicknav

I'm trying to change the labels in Slicknav for when the Slicknav menu is opened and closed.

[In the jsfiddle, here.](http://jsfiddle.net/913vm2mq/) I've used label closed for the default state, and for the open state another piece of text I would like another piece of text.

Like this for the normal state:

```
$('#menu').slicknav({
    duplicate: false,
    label: 'label closed'
});
```

I've tried using basic if this then that and I feel like I'm just messing up this very simple piece of javascript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a short look on the [docs](http://slicknav.com/)
Something like this should do the trick.

```
var $label;
$('#menu').slicknav({
    duplicate: false,
    label: 'label closed',
    init: function() {
        $label = $(".slicknav_menutxt");
    },
    open: function() {
        $label.text("label open");
    },
    close: function() {
        $label.text("label closed");
    } 
});
```

Also the link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd4tzf94/1/)

Comment: It definetly did in the example I provided. However, I'm trying to include an <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> to use a different hamburger icon.

And for the label closed I wanted to use a close icon, you see?

However I can't seem to include an <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> like that in the $label.text("label open");

Thank you for your time

Comment: The plugin adds some classes `slicknav_open` and `slicknav_collapsed` you can use those and update the icon from css

Comment: If you want to include html instead of text use the `html` jQuery method instead of the `text` one. If you only want to change the icon you can do that from css only based on the open/collapsed classes I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you, I was just working the wrong way. I've got it now thanks! I included FontAwesome into css using @font-face and used :before to specify an icon to that slicknav_open and slicknav_collapsed class.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the text directly as it's contained in a span with the class `slicknav_menutxt` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd4tzf94/)

```
$('#open').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#menu').slicknav('open');
  $(".slicknav_menutxt").text("label open");

});

$('#close').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#menu').slicknav('close');
  $(".slicknav_menutxt").text("label closed");

});

$('#toggle').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($(".slicknav_menutxt").text().indexOf("open") >= 0) {
    $(".slicknav_menutxt").text("label closed");
   } else {
    $(".slicknav_menutxt").text("label open");
  }
  $('#menu').slicknav('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Hmm yes that's a good solution. However, I'm trying to implement it  to the " $('#menu').slicknav({ " function, not just on a toggle.